# Rails ActiveRecord using recently saved record id in after_save callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback, after-save

I want to use recently stored record ID in after_save callback, is that possible if yes how?

`after_save :create_children



def create_children

 self.id

end`

Update:
Sorry there was something going wrong with my save function, my bad, sorry to waste your time

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just tried it with this:

```
 class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
   after_save :test_me

   def test_me
     puts self.id
   end
 end
```

and in the console:

```
$ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 3.0.4)
>> x=Thing.new
=> #<Thing id: nil, name: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
>> x.save
2
=> true
>> y=Thing.create
3
=> #<Thing id: 3, name: nil, created_at: "2011-04-27 15:57:03", updated_at: "2011-04-27 15:57:03">
```

What else is going on in your model?

Comment: At least in MySql, the auto increment id column has to be set as the primary key. I had a problem where my primary key was made up of two fields -- and so ActiveRecord wouldn't read the Id. I changed it to just the ID field and the code started working.

Answer (score 1):

if you call reload() after saving the object, the self.id will be populated

Comment: I tried it out, but it didnt work

Comment: I tried to use after_create as well with no luck

Comment: **Sugesstion**: If it is a post-processing and shouldn't affect saving of the model object, you can do it in your `after_commit` callback