# Rails 'after_save' callback contains an empty 'self'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback

I have a problem I cannot diagnose.  I have an after_save callback in one of my models that correctly fires the callback and correctly creates/saves the model to the DB, but when I interrogate the values in 'self' (to perform some other action with the values I have ommited here due to NDA) the model appears as being empty.

Example:

```
after_save :automatically_map

private

def automatically_map
  put self.id
end
```

The callback correctly fires when I create or save a model, however self.id is 'nil' - and all the other attributes have defaulted to their blank/new object values.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: similar problem - http://stackoverflow.com/a/5807026

Comment: sometimes we need to reload object, try `self.reload` before puts `self.id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe, it's happened because db did not commited transaction. You can try to use

> after_commit :automatically_map, on: :create